# Tuple Attributes? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, tuples

Not sure how to fix this? I know little about .format, and I am using:

```
printedxrows = [ ("[X]","[X]","[X]","[X]","[X]","  <- V: {}   TOTAL: {}")
             .format(row.count(0), sum(row))
             for row in rows ]
```

I am getting this error:

```
    for row in rows ]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Comment: Are you trying to produce a tuple of strings or a string with parenthesis around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`("[X]","[X]","[X]","[X]","[X]","  <- V: {}   TOTAL: {}")` is a tuple, not a string.

You want to call `str.format()` on the last element here, which is a string object:

```
("[X]", "[X]", "[X]", "[X]", "[X]", "  <- V: {}   TOTAL: {}".format(row.count(0), sum(row)))
```